# Chamar uma página HTML passando informações para banco MySQL via PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Olá!**
Assumi um projeto aqui na empresa, onde foi proposto fazer um pré-questionário para o usuário antes que ele acessasse um questionário. Até determinado ponto o usuário navega entre as possibilidades e em um ponto ele tem que responder algumas coisas, que é onde estou travado.
Estou fazendo o site em HTML e não precisei usar PHP até agora. Neste momento precisarei utilizar. Temos a base de dados instalada e configurada, só preciso saber utilizar agora!
A dúvida é a seguinte:
Como eu posso chamar a página seguinte, passando para o banco o valor que o usuário selecionou e carregando a página que se refere à escolha do usuário?
Exemplificando:

**Você procurou seu gestor imediato?**
**-** Sim **->** Passar para o banco o valor 'yes' **->** Carregar a página que corresponde à resposta afirmativa.

Depois disso, numa próxima tela, terei que coletar o que o usuário digitar também, então preciso saber como passo o que ele digitou após clicar em "Prosseguir".
Então, amigos! Como eu posso fazer isto?
Não mexo com PHP tem MUITO tempo e aceitei esta tarefa como um desafio. Consegui implementar coisas muito legais e esta, que é a parte mais importante, estou travado... Talvez exausto por ter que recordar tanta coisa até aqui!

Então esta é a pergunta!
Qual o melhor método para validar o que o usuário escolheu/digitou, enviar para o banco e então carregar a página referente à escolha do usuário? Ah! O detalhe é que as informações serão inseridas aos poucos... Tipo, o usuário responde à primeira pergunta (do tipo Boolean), a mesma é armazenada, então o banco vai "esperar" o próximo input, ainda na mesma ID. Então quando o usuário digitar e clicar em 'avançar' será enviado o texto digitado (do tipo VarChar) e aguardar o próximo input. Ao finalizar, o usuário será redirecionado ao Questionário, que já está pronto. Neste questionário ele fará mais alguns inputs, acrescentando ao ID do Pré-questionário. Se isto for muito difícil de fazer, eu posso concatenar esses dados quando for fazer o relatório - que é o que precisam - no final do questionário.
O que eu desenvolvi no HTML foi basicamente... Nada. Tô muito sem saber o que vou usar! A parte onde o usuário escolhe entre Sim e Não é a que segue:

```
    <div id="content">      
    <p><br>Você procurou seu Gestor Imediato para resolver a situação que deseja relatar na Ouvidoria Interna?</p> 
    <nav>
    <ul class="group" id="menu">
        <form action="" method="get" id="validar">
        <li>
        <input type="hidden" name="submit_sim" />
        <a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('validar').submit();">Sim</a></li>
        <li>
        <input type="hidden" name="submit_nao" />
        <a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('validar').submit();">Não</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Vou validar a conexão no conecta.php e então inserir os dados na tabela via &_GET. É o melhor método, certo!? :)

Então é isto! 
Esta é minha primeira pergunta aqui, então me desculpem se infligi alguma regra e me corrijam se faltei com alguma informação.
Lembrando que não quero nada mastigado, quero apenas um direcionamento de o que devo usar e como, se possível! Obrigado à todos!

Comment: Cara já que é sua primeira vez aqui perde uns minutinhos aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour dá uma editada e coloca algum código que esteja testando...

Comment: O problema é que eu não tenho praticamente nada desenvolvido! Só a "cara" da página. A comunidade auxilia dando 'direcionamento', ou só ajudando com erros/bugs? Realmente não sei, rs. Eu havia feito o tour, mas muito obrigado de qualquer forma!

Comment: Seria legal dividir o problema em partes menores, e perguntar passo a passo, à medida em que for resolvendo suas dúvidas. Além de uma lida no tour, conforme o @MagicHat mencionou, é bom conhecer o [escopo do site](/help/on-topic), uma lida em [ask] e na [help] para entender como aproveitar melhor. Coisas muito amplas, ou que dependam apenas de opinião não funcionam muito bem no formato Pergunta&Respostas.

Comment: E lembre-se de dar uma pesquisada sobre assuntos parecidos pelo site. Talvez parte do que você quer saber já tenha respostas, e é uma ótima maneira de ver o tipo de pergunta que funciona bem aqui, e atrai respostas melhores, e o tipo de pergunta que não surte tanto efeito. Dito isto, seja bem-vindo e eu espero que os links mencionados possam ajudar você a fazer um bom proveito do site.